# User "last seen" on March 17th, but has an answer from March 24th

Tags: support, profile-page

[This user](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/10264/t%E1%B4%9Ao%C9%AF%C9%90uo) has posted a answer on [March 24](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/202140/difference-between-these-2-reduced-clauses/202141#202141), but their profile
page shows **March 17** as "Last seen".

[image]

In this [archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190707043629/https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/10264/t%E1%B4%9Ao%C9%AF%C9%90uo), you can click on "Newest" to view the bug clearly.

Is this a bug in the "Last seen" functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well spotted, but no, this is not a bug.

The question and its answer were posted on a *different* site, and then (five hours after posting the answer) the post was migrated to its current site, where the user was last seen one week earlier. See the [timeline](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/491069/timeline) of the question on its original site:

[image: timeline]

So even while their *content* is on English Language Learners, they never actually visited the site that day. So for instance, this wouldn't count towards the [Fanatic badge](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/badges/55/fanatic).

Comment: This is a duplicate. I asked the same question perhaps 3 months ago and you gave the same answer.

Comment: Heh, I must've forgotten about that. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Also I don't think it's appropriate nor necessary to name the user

Comment: It would be kinda hard to analyze this 'bug' without linking to the profile...

Comment: I managed to make it anonymous.